# A word for a man who doesn't get upset about his wife's relationships

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for a man who doesn't care about his wife, sister or girlfriend's relationships.

For example: He is OK with his wife being kissed by every man and somehow encourages her to do so.

> I **don't mean** a person who is **open-minded**, Rather a person who is weak and somehow like **potato**. Of course a real man gets angry in that condition and in some situations tells her wife to dress clothes which are less revealing.

> And, Is there a word which is opposite for that **potato** man. A man who cares.
>   Edit: A real man fights against somebody who stares at his wife/sister.

Comment: Based on the comments you've made below, I'm assuming you want something you can say to a friend. "Be a man. Man up. Don't be a wuss." But note that these are expressions are meant to be used with good friends who will appreciate hearing the cold, hard truth from you. Do not use these in polite company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A man who does nothing while his wife behaves inappropriately with other men is sometimes called a *cuckold*, or *cuckhold*, or is being *cuckholded*.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that there are no opposites. Right? And my examples. Do these make sense? _Her husband is a cuckold. He let's his wife to dress badly in front of strangers. **OR** Don't be a cuckold. Say something to your girlfriend. Show everybody that you're her owner._

Comment: Yes, they both make sense. Cuckold generally implies that the woman has physical relations with other men, but in the context of your sentence, it works. As an aside - you do not need the apostrophe in 'lets'.

Comment: And last question: No opposite? Someone who cares about his wife's clothes and relationships!

Comment: There isn't really an opposite. You might say the man was 'in control' or simply tell him to 'be a man'.

Answer (score 5):

I once asked a question on EL&U asking for the female equivalent of this term, **wittol**, a very rare  word which  I discovered in my Chambers Dictionary. It said, *a man who knows his wife's unfaithfulness, and accepts it*.

In a few online dictionaries the term is defined

> **[wittol](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wittol)** (ˈwɪtəl)
>   a man who tolerates his wife's unfaithfulness
>   [C15 *wetewold*, from *witen* to know (see wit²) + -*wold*, perhaps from *cokewold* cuckold]

A historical example, from *[Kenilworth](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1606/1606-h/1606-h.htm)* by Sir Walter Scott

> She would not quit the estate and title of the **wittol** who had wedded her.
>   [...]
>   Go to Elizabeth’s feet, confess your marriage—impeach your wife and her paramour of adultery—and avow yourself, amongst all your peers, the **wittol** who married a country girl, and was cozened by her and her book-learned gallant.

The term *cuckold*, although far more common is quite different, inasmuch as the husband is usually unaware of his wife's extramarital affairs.

*[a man whose wife **deceives him** by having a sexual relationship with another man](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cuckold)*

Answer (score 0):

The word that comes to mind for me is [**voyeur**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/voyeur) - a person who watching others when they are naked or engaged in sexual activity. Generally, this person gets sexual pleasure from watching others having sex. Traditionally a voyeur would watch unsuspecting couples, but in the modern age, the definition extends itself to willing participants, including within a marriage.

Comment: Thank you. But that's **not** the word I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Merriam-Webster https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meek

Meek (adj.)

> 1  enduring injury with patience and without resentment :  mild *a meek child dominated by his brothers* 
>   2  deficient in spirit and courage :  submissive *“I don't care,” came the meek reply — Annetta Miller*
>   3  not violent or strong :  moderate *His delivery varied from a meek, melodic patter to rapid-fire scriptural allusions — Bob Trebilcock*

For the opposite I would go for

> alpha male

Comment: Is this Ok? _His brother gets alpha male whenever he sees her sister with a new man, His blood runs wild_ OR _Don't be/get alpha male. World has changed._

Comment: And also: _Her husband is meek. He let's his wife to dress badly in front of strangers._ **OR** _Don't be meek. Say something to your girlfriend. Show everybody that you're her owner._

Comment: Answers that are mostly content copied from other sites are discouraged. I think showing how meek and 'alpha male' would be used in the context the OP has asked about would make this a much better answer.

Answer (score -2):

Cuckquen is the male version of cuckold. I think this is the answer you are looking for.i don't know how old this post is but I thought people could use the correct answer., So they understand what the question is better cause I don't think they get what you were asking . Cuckquen is the only word for the male version of cuckold yet there are many version of cuckold wittol is one of them

Comment: Do you mean "cuck*quean*"? That refers to woman with a husband who has sex with many women, not the other way around (so it doesn't answer the question).